# Any Public Videos of Anyone Playing Jupiter Mission 1999?

Tags: commodore-64, gaming, atari-800

When I was growing up, I played a game for the Atari 800 entitled "Jupiter Mission 1999", which has as a premise that you wake up in the middle of the night with astronauts at your door and they tell you that you're going to Jupiter with them.  I've searched for videos to watch someone doing a "let's play" on YouTube, Twitch, and using the search engine DuckDuckGo, but all I've gotten is some articles about it, such as the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Mission_1999)

Have I missed something?  Is there some public video of someone playing this game somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I recall the ads for this game being among the most enticing I had ever seen in the era, and one of my earlier examples of must-have-itis.

I recently tried playing the game with the aid of an emulator. I was rather disappointed to learn that it consists of a series of mini-games, including ones that had been released separately as stand-alone games, notably Space Cowboy.

My suggestion is to simply download an emulator, a set of 400/800 ROMs and have at it. Disk images are [widely available](http://www.atarimania.com/game-atari-400-800-xl-xe-jupiter-mission-1999_2721.html). You *will* go nuts waiting for loads.

Comment: I do remember the load times on the game being quite bad.  I did enjoy the game though.